# JavaScript: Taking the highest 2 numerical values out of a series of 4 possible values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take the highest two values out of 4 possible variables and add them together, while ignoring the lesser two values. My values will be anywhere between 1 and 5.

So, for example, if I have the variables:

```
Trait 1 = 3
Trait 2 = 3
Trait 3 = 2
Trait 4 = 1
```

The script should pick up the 3 and the 3, but not the 2 and the 1. If I change the values around so that I have:

```
Trait 1 = 4
Trait 2 = 3
Trait 3 = 1
Trait 4 = 5
```

The script should use the 4 and the 5, but not the 3 and the 1. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you refactor such that you're storing values in an array rather than in variables that happen to have names that only suggest related values?

Answer (score 2):

Put them in an array and then sort the array descending.
After sorting, you'll have the values you need in the first two members.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider this approach: (on the same lines as the other answers)

```
var Trait1 = 4;
var Trait2 = 3;
var Trait3 = 1;
var Trait4 = 5;

var sorted = [Trait1, Trait2, Trait3, Trait4].sort(function (a, b) { 
   return b - a; 
});

console.log(sorted[0] + sorted[1]);    // returns 9
```

Further reading:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Sort)

Comment: This is the best answer, providing working code to back up the technique, and avoids the potential pitfall of not providing a comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are passing the data in as an array of values, aka:

```
var array = [4, 3, 1, 5];

array.sort(); // becomes [1, 3, 4, 5]

var item1 = newArray[array.length - 1];
var item2 = newArray[array.length - 2];
```

Just sort and you have the values. Here's a page talking about sorting: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

Comment: That would give 4 insead of 9 :)

Comment: This won't work without providing a comparison function because the default sort is lexical. Hence `[4, 3, 10, 5].sort()` will give you `[10, 3, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 0):

What Vanco said in code:

```
var myarray=[1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 1, 8]
myarray.sort().reverse();
alert(myarray[0] + myarray[1]);
```